# Angular HttpClient Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rxjs, observable

I have a service where I perform http requests to my API and then I made services for other purposes that passes url's to the http request service. But when I try to add a model to my `get` request I get the `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1` error.

**calendar.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
// WebReq for http requests 
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';
import { ICalendarEvent } from '../../models/calendar-event.model';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CalendarService {

    constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) { }

    // Where I get the error
    getCalendarEvent(): Observable<ICalendarEvent[]> {
        return this.webReqService.get<ICalendarEvent[]>('/calendars');
    }

}
```

**web-request.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebRequestService {

  readonly _url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this._url = 'some url';
  }

  get(uri: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this._url}/${uri}`);
  }

  post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this._url}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  patch(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.patch(`${this._url}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  delete(uri: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this._url}/${uri}`);
  }


}
```

**calendar-event.model.ts**

```
export interface ICalendarEvent {
    id: number;
    start: string;
    end: string;
    title: string;
    estimate_number: string;
    brand: string;
    meters: string;
    floor: string;
    floor_type: string;
    plint_type: string;
    floor_installer: number;
    city: string;
    street: string;
    postal_code: string;
    province: string;
    notes: string;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to call a function with a type parameter then you need to add the generic type parameter to the declaration.

If you want to get the full benefit of doing this, I would recommend adding a return type to your function.

```js
get<T>(uri: string): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.get<T>(`${this._url}/${uri}`);
}
```

Comment: Your answer along with [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types) helped me understand this better. Thank you Kurt

Comment: No problem. They're difficult to understand at first, but they are powerful once you start to understand them. I've been using them in C# for years, so they feel natural to me now. It's important to remember that in Typescript, just because you have declared a type, it doesn't necessarily mean that you have an instance of that type. Typescript is just a coding-time helper. We're still just writing Javascript in the end.